# Build rptproj from reports folder to use with SVN

Tags: svn, reporting-services

We have multiple developers working to create SSRS reports and we're using SVN for version control.  The problem is we're switching all reports from Crystal so all of us are constantly adding new reports to the project.  Almost every time that happens, the rptproj file has conflicts and you have to merge the conflicts and then go back in and add local files that got dropped from the merge, or the commit fails because you have to update your working copy, or something is out of date and it fails.

This is a huge pain and some of our less technical people who are good at building reports are getting frustrated at the constant versioning issues.

What's the best way to handle this type of situation, it seems very hacky to just version the actual Reports folder with all the rdl/rsd/rds files and have everyone manually make an empty local project and add files that way.

I'm coming from a small VSS 2005 shop and the main SVN champion here has left and I'm not super familiar with SVN.  I must be missing something because it just doesn't seem to be working for us with SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

We often have this problem with our projects. My suggestion is not to merge the rptproj file. Just add the new files and then manually add them to the project afterwards.

The other thing we do is to spilt then solution up into smaller projects, that makes merges easier.

The problem is that this is a machine generated file and things really get mixed around in it.

Regards
(we are using git, so I am speaking from that point of view.)